# Audio/Video live streaming between two browsers, which technologies?

Tags: javascript, python, html, open-source, streaming

I'm searching for the best open source technologies to use to implement a bidirectional audio/video communication between two browsers.
For now I have unearthed these tracks:

- [WebRTC](http://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/) W3C spec and an [Ericsson's implementation](https://labs.ericsson.com/apis/web-real-time-communication/)
- Red5 and the [BigBlueButton implementation](http://www.bigbluebutton.org/) as an example
- [Cumulus](https://github.com/OpenRTMFP/Cumulus) A Red5 implementation of Cirrus
- HTML5 and his many new features (but not before 2014-2015 aparently)
- Maybe some Jabber/Speex kind of implementation that I'm missing

Is there something I'm missing ?
What can be the best solution to use ?

Also (to be more precise), I'd like to implement this feature in my application developped using Django/Python.

Comment: My guess is this question is too broad. I see you mention unrelated technologies that may very well be all used in the implementation of a service to implement "bidirectional a/v communication between two browsers" depending on the architecture you choose and the requirements you want to fulfil.

For example, Erlang is mostly a server side technology whereas HTML5 is client side

Comment: Yes I was hoping that by canvassing large (server or client side technologies) I could engender a response leading to a viable solution.

Comment: @SamuelRivas: the question sounds too brad, but it's not, it seems to me. A/V communications is a rather specific area, and viable open source solutions are not quite numerous here; solutions accessible from a browser are even fewer. Server-side technologies are numerous, but it's a bit different.

Comment: @Glide: I'd separate your list into server-side techs (these are numerous) and client-side browser-based techs (these are few). Also, I'd remove too general things, like Erlang, from the list; you can list many decent languages for the same reason, without any connection to A/V communication.

Comment: You are right for Erlang, it's removed. Some items are both client and server sides so I don't really know how to separate things. Anyway there are only 5 remaining so it's still readable. Feel free to edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hardest question is what you should use on the client side to capture and stream video from the user's webcam. For that, you have relatively few options, since whatever you use has to be widely supported by modern browsers, whereas you can do whatever you want on your own servers.

There are three general approaches you can take: use HTML5, use an existing plugin technology, or create your own plugin.

The third is probably the most difficult, and I don't recommend it. You'd need to maintain at least five different versions of your plugin (one for each major browser), and users would have to install it.

For the second option, there are three major plugin techologies now that ActiveX is dead: Flash, Silverlight, and Java applets. I'd advise you away from Silverlight, as it's not exactly portable.

That leaves you with Flash, applets, and HTML5 as your choices. Of these, Flash is the most widely used—but it has its disadvantages and the world is moving away from it. HTML5 is the wave of the future, and although the standard won't be finished until 2014, it's not expected to change (Last Call was in May 2011) and the major browsers already support much of it—though apparently not yet the WebRTC API, though I'm sure it'll be in Firefox and Chrome soon.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to build something similar to [Chatroulette](http://chatroulette.com/)? They support bi-directional video streaming and microphones. They use Flash Player 10's peer-to-peer ability and Wowza Media Server to power their site.

Comment: That's not open-source technologies is it ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the realistic answer for where we're at today is Flash. Fortunately, there is haxe, an open source compiler for the Flash SWF format. You could use it to make [all kinds of stuff](http://code.google.com/p/haxevideo/).

The server in the linked example is written in haxe (basically AS3) and compiled to instructions for NekoVM (an apache module) but it should provide a pretty good example if nothing else.